# c# / WPF : Make a Browse for File Dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog

I'm new to WPF and am trying to make my first WPF desktop application using VC# Express.

I'm trying to get make three open file dialogs complete with text fields that show the specified path if the user chooses a file. I found working code to make the dialog box appear at the click of a button, but how do I get a text field to update/bind to the file path?

Something similar to how the file input boxes in HTML work would be ideal.

...

EDIT:

Okay I read the post just below mine and found the solution...

Now, how about redirecting console output to a text field?

Comment: Why would you want to redirect Console output to a textbox? Diagnostics? Logging?

Comment: Please ask different questions in a different question.  :)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about redirecting console output:

You'll be better off changing the code to fire an event with the string you wish to output. Then in the UI add a handler for that event and in the handler update the text field.

To declare an event add something like this code in your processing class:

```
public event EventHandler<StringEventArgs> Process_Message;
```

where `StringEventArgs` is a class based on `EventArgs` that wraps the message for sending.

To fire the event add something like this code in your processing class:

```
Process_Message(this, new StringEventArgs(message));
```

To attach a message handler in your UI class:

```
process.Process_Message += Process_Message;
```

To handle the event add something like this code to your UI class:

```
private void Process_Message(object sender, StringEventArgs e)
{
     Action action = () => UpdateStatus(e.Message);
     {
         Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, action);
     }
     else
     {
            action();
     }         
}
```

You need to do the threading test as the UI can't be updated from a different thread.

Then the `UpdateStatus` method:

```
private void UpdateStatus(string message)
{
    statusTextBox.Text = message;
}
```

Obviously you'll need to rename things to be appropriate to your application.

Look up events and `EventArgs` in the MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly
Use the FileDialog.FileName to the the Full path .. and bind that to your text box.
76mel